# Alter a populated table datatype in a specific column

Tags: mysql, editing

I am a newbie in mysql and have looked at existing posts but dont find exactly the answer required.
I have created a table in myphpadmin but when I inserted data via php and lloked at he data I found thet a decimal data type had truncated the entry. I had entered type as decimal instead of decimal(3,2) i.e. e.g. 4.25.However I have nor been able to find any guideline on how to correct this data type.
I tried (# indicates intentionally masked entries)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>
      <title>Hello!</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "###";
    $password = "########";
    $dbname = "stdata";

   // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   ?>
   <?php
   $sql = "ALTER TABLE pp01
   ALTER COLUMN natr decimal(3,2);

   $conn->close();
   ?>

   </body>
   </html>
```

This ends up with:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\Inetpub\vhosts####.com\httpdocs####`enter code here`\DATA_ALTER.php on line 28

Comment: I think you are missing a `"` after your query string?

Comment: Also you need execute the command before closing the connetion. And not sure how php works, But you dont need create separated `<?php>` tags. Not sure if  that create separated blocks